# In Enterpise Architect cannot add interruption flow

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm fairly new to Enterprise Architect, thus the question might be very simple. I'm modelling an activity diagram. The flow is pretty straightforward. However, I cannot add an interrupt flow between two actions. 
Here's the behavior of the system: a user presses a button, while he's holding the button, the machine is moving towards the target. As soon as the machine reached the target, the application proceeds to the next step. If the user releases the button, the machine stops and waits till he presses it again to re-start the movement.
Here's the description of my model: I have the action "Press button", the control flow goes inside of the InterruptibleActivityRegion. Inside of the region I iteratively check if the target is reached. I also have action "Release button". I want to add interruption flow from it to the very beginning (to go before button press action). However, I can't. when I right-click on the Release button action, only control flow or object flow can be created. I've tried clicking on interruption flow in the Toolbox, but whenever I click on the Release button action, it's not added. I've also tried to use Receive instead of Action for Release button - only control flow can be added to it. Do you have any idea why interruption flow cannot be added?

Comment: If you switch off strict syntax checking, you can add interrupt flows anywhere you like. With strict syntax checking on, however, they have to follow the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution. The reason why I couldn't connect the action which is a cause of the interruption to a different action with a interruption flow is that the first action didn't belong to the interruption region. When I created the action, I placed it inside of the region, but didn't check in the object browser which element became its parent. After moving the action to be a child of the region, I'm able to connect it with an interruption flow to other actions.

Answer (score 1):

The connector might not be available in the quick-link menu (which is displayed when you drag a connector from one element to another in a diagram), but it should still be in the activity diagram toolbox, next to control and object flow.

Comment: It is in the toolbox. But that's exactly the problem - when I select it and click on the activity which I want to use as an interruption source, it doesn't let me do that. I wonder if there are certain conditions I'm missing